# Is there a way to use Docker Container IPs variable?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, docker, symfony-3.4

I'm dockerizing an existing Symfony-project which uses MongoDB to store data. So I set up an Apache-Container which works fine for the Symfony-part and a MongoDB-Container to run the database. But now when I try to connect the both, I need to fill in the MongoDB-Container-IP in the `parameters.yml` of symfony like this:

`mongodb_server: 'mongodb://172.21.0.2:27017'`

using the IP-Adress I found out with `docker inspect ${mongodb_container}` .

So my question is: Is there a better way to send the MongoDB-container-IP to the `parameters.yml` so it won't break for example when the IPs change?

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need the IP address.

Run your application using

`docker run --name some-app --link your-mongo-container-name:mongo -d application-that-uses-mongo`

with --link you can access your mongo by hostname. Like 
`mongodb_server: 'mongodb://mongo:27017'`

--link is deprecated now, but this will work for you now. 
In future put these two containers in the same network.

And then call them using their hostname.